# VB.net Scope issue - variables not being set from function

Tags: vb.net, oop, scope

(edit: Solved in comments by Plutonix - Class should be used instead of Structure)

I am creating a tool to merge points from a 3d model.
The points are all stored in a list of structures 'Point3', and the MergePoints Sub is designed to iterate through the list to find points within a tolerance value of each other. It would then set the 'redirect' value of the latter point to the index of the former.
The 'Compare' function is reached, and the redirect variable is set locally when stepped through.
However, the problem is that the redirect value within the list is never set.

From what I understand of scope it should have worked. After all, the New function works correctly on the same principle. Every example I have found online seems to say it works.
Is it perhaps copying the instance when I call 'points(i).Compare()'?

Thank you in advance for any help.

Source code (snippet):

```
Dim points As List(Of Point3)
Dim tolerance As Double = 0.000001

Structure Point3
    Dim x As Double
    Dim y As Double
    Dim z As Double

    Dim redirect As Integer

    Sub New(_x As Double, _y As Double, _z As Double)
        x = _x
        y = _y
        z = _z
        redirect = -1
    End Sub

    Function Compare(ByRef other As Point3, pos As Integer) As Boolean
        If Math.Abs(other.x - x) < Merge.tolerance AndAlso Math.Abs(other.y - y) < Merge.tolerance AndAlso Math.Abs(other.z - z) < Merge.tolerance Then
            redirect = pos
            'MsgBox(redirect)

            Return True
        Else
            Return False
        End If
    End Function
End Structure

Sub MergePoints()
    Dim j As UInteger

    For i As UInteger = 1 To points.Count - 1
        j = 0
        Do Until j = i OrElse points(i).Compare(points(j), j)
            j += 1
        Loop
    Next

    For Each p As Point3 In points
        If p.redirect > -1 Then
            MsgBox(p.x & ", " & p.y & ", " & p.z)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: This is confusing since you never clearly describe a problem, just your confusion.  I cant see when `Scope` comes into play or would be an issue
 Also, `Point3` should probably be a class

Comment: The problem is that the variable is not set to the Point3 in the list. I tried with a class, and it works fine now. I was under the impression that classes and structs were almost identical. Is there a difference with the way functions are handled? Thanks.

Comment: Ah, yes. Looking at Microsoft Docs, it states. 'Structures are value types; classes are reference types. A variable of a structure type contains the structure's data, rather than containing a reference to the data as a class type does.' - therefore I was attempting to assign a value to THE structure, not an instance of it. Thank you for helping.

Comment: [Choosing Between Class and Struct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/choosing-between-class-and-struct)